# can we code to find negative number and positive number using ternary operator in java

Tags: java, ternary

can we code to identify positive number and negative number in java using ternary operator.

```
import java.util.*;
public class negative{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        (a>=0)?System.out.print("positive number"):System.out.print("negative number");

    }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;
public class negative{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        (a>=0)?System.out.print("positive number"):System.out.print("negative number");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between both code snippets? Did you try it?

Comment: not sure if that what yo looking for or not         System.out.print((a >= 0) ? "positive number" : "negative number");

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you cannot use the Ternary operator like this. The ternary operator should always result in some value in java. This code will cause an error because of the print statement.

One other way of using ternary opertor for above checking positive or negative number is this way (it wont cause an error):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Negative {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println((a >= 0) ? "positive number" : "negative number");
  }
}
```